# JFR: OutOfMemoryError while reading .jfr file

Tags: java, openjdk-11, jfr

I'm trying to analyze a large Flight Recorder file (1.5 GB) that I created previously. When executing the `jfr print` command, the tool runs into an OutOfMemoryError:

```
$ jfr print --events "jdk.CPULoad" <file>

jfr print: unexpected internal error, Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ParserFactory$CompositeParser.parse(ParserFactory.java:283)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ParserFactory$ArrayParser.parse(ParserFactory.java:268)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ParserFactory$CompositeParser.parse(ParserFactory.java:285)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ChunkParser.fillConstantPools(ChunkParser.java:141)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ChunkParser.<init>(ChunkParser.java:71)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.ChunkParser.<init>(ChunkParser.java:56)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.RecordingFile.findNext(RecordingFile.java:253)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.consumer.RecordingFile.<init>(RecordingFile.java:108)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.internal.tool.EventPrintWriter.print(EventPrintWriter.java:71)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.internal.tool.Print.execute(Print.java:165)
    at jdk.jfr/jdk.jfr.internal.tool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

Is there a way to increase the heap size (`-Xmx`) for the `jfr` tool itself? I haven't found a corresponding option in the documentation. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try the disassemble and then print each chunks ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the file only consists of 1 chunk. When trying to disassemble it into pieces of max 250MB, I get:`File consists of 1 chunks. The recording will be split into 1 files` and the file stays at 1.5 GB

Comment: Try setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with a higher Xmx in the OS variables and run JFR.

Comment: Good to know it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Kris, there is an environment variable that can be used: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`

In my case, the following did the trick:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx5G"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass JVM options by using the -J prefix, for example:

```
$ jfr -J-Xmx3048m print --events "jdk.CPULoad" <file>
```

Normally the file size should not matter. Data comes in chunks, each about 10-15 MB, and memory is released when a new chunk begins, but it looks like everything is in one chunk, perhaps because it was emitted during a very short period, so the JVM didn't have a chance to rotate the file.

Future version of the JDK may allow filtering, i.e. extract all CPULoad events into a file.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8269767